# Sound not playing with QSoundEffect when deployed

Tags: windows, qt, audio, qt5

I'm having a problem that I'm finding hard to debug. My program needs to play sounds from time to time (often overlapping several sound files at once). I mostly develop on a mac, and the mac build works fine (packaged using the macdeployqt utility that comes with Qt), however the windows build will only play sounds on the machine it was compiled on. Everyone I've shipped it to to test has failed to get any sound (although I have confirmed it is finding the sound files correctly, so it's definitely not that).

On startup (called from the main window constructor) I load each file like this:

```
QSoundEffect *tmpSfx = new QSoundEffect();
QUrl pathAsURL;
pathAsURL = pathAsURL.fromLocalFile(fileList.at(i).absoluteFilePath());
if (tmpSfx)
{
    qDebug() << "path" << pathAsURL;
    tmpSfx->setSource(pathAsURL);
    tmpSfx->setLoopCount(1);
    tmpSfx->setVolume(0.4);
 // tmpSfx->play();
    qDebug() << "is loaded" << tmpSfx->isLoaded();
    SoundsList.append(tmpSfx)
```

Where SoundsList is a `QList<QSoundEffect *>`.

Then when I need to play a sound, I call:

```
SoundsList.at(SoundIndex)->play();
```

On windows I'm distributing the application as a zip file, with all the required Qt DLL's alongside it. At least, all the Qt DLL's that I *think* are required.

```
Qt5Core.dll
Qt5Gui.dll
Qt5Multimedia.dll
Qt5Network.dll
Qt5Widgets.dll
icudt52.dll
icuin52.dll
icuuc52.dll
libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll
libstdc++-6.dll
libwinpthread-1.dll
platforms\qwindows.dll
```

Am I missing anything obvious?

When run on the machine I use to build it, it works fine. When run on that same machine without the DLL's in the same folder, it fails, unless I run it from Qt Creator, which is how I worked out the dependencies on most of those DLL's. When it is run from any other windows machine, it runs just fine with no errors, but also no sound output.

It's written in Qt 5.2, and built using Creator and MinGW.

Comment: Most probably related to missing DLLs. I have never used it before but can you try including the audio/qtaudio_windows.dll in your executable folder ? (It exists in the plugins directory of Qt)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most probably you are missing the qtaudio_windows.dll which is located in plugins\audio\qtaudio_windows.dll. When deployed it should be in the app's dir in subfolder named "audio".

Answer (score 0):

The problem is most probably in the way you address the file. You can print the value of pathAsURL, after it is set, to see what it is set to, but it is generally a bad habit to address files like that, because the path to the file is most probably hardcoded to its location on your computer. Instead, import the files, used in your program, as resources.